# Does Auto insurance remain in effect for teen driver, if policy holders die

Tags: united-states, insurance, car-insurance, teenager

Sorry to ask this weird question.

Auto insurance is bought by Parents and names Parents as insured and lists teenager as authorized driver.

God forbid, if for some reason parents die( in auto or non auto accident or other wise). Will the Auto insurance cease to exist immediately? ( Even if the premium is already paid for the policy full term)

Can the teenager still drive till the policy's expiration date ?

Comment: I feel like this will depend massively on the wording of the actual policy, and in addition on the country - not sure it is possible to give a general answer

Comment: @andrew yes, what i understand upto a minimum lots of documents and procedures in USA are standardized. For example on Bonds there are about 1000+ pages written as contract and i doubt if anyone reads them

Comment: maybe call your policy holder and just ask them straight out?

Comment: I think this is a law.se question and should be transferred there. It basically asks what happens to a contract, in this case insurance, after one party dies.

Comment: Who’s going to renew the policy?

Comment: The policy certainly has fine print covering this situation.

Comment: @ronjohn fine print is not easy to read or understand

Comment: Well, yes, but the answer is definitely in there.  Fortunately in 2022, this is all online and in PDF format.  Search the document for words like "dead", "die" and "deceased".

Answer (score 1):

The exact age of the person will be important. A 16 year will likely be unable to sign the required legal documents. While a 19 year old will probably be able to sign the documents.

So if the policy included all the drivers in the household, and all the ones over 18 are deceased the coverage would lapse. If they are over 18 the policy can be reissued in the name of the teenager.

The exact state will also be important a state could set a minimum age higher than 18. All insurance in the US has an state component.

If the a family member becomes the teenagers guardian, then the teen could be added to their policy.

Comment: @mhoran-psprep I guess with **a state could set a minimum age higher than 18** you mean **legal age for being adult** ?

Comment: I don't think this age relates here, what i get is https://www.bhwlawfirm.com/legal-age-consent-united-states-map/ but does not seem to be related to Auto insurance. So if you have a link tat list all state that will clearify

Comment: @puzzled age of consent for sex is not the same as age of legal maturity (that is, age at which you can sign binding contracts), which AFAIK is universally 18 in the US.

Comment: @littleadv thanks, I said in my comment that the link should not be the one, but a similar link. So in USA all states have 18 years to sign for contract ?

Comment: No, you can be younger when you sign a contract, but the contract is voidable if the minor or their guardian changes their mind.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question specifically talks about an existing paid-up policy. Signing a new policy is irrelevant, as a contract already exists between the insurer and now the decedent's estate.